# attach a file into the mail from unix db server through plsql

Tags: email, plsql, oracle11g, smtp, email-attachments

I want to send the content of a table as a mail attachment using utl_smtp.

I am able to extract the content from the table into an excel file by implementing a package mentioned in this url ( https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/ )

Now the file is available in the DB server, under a directory.

How can I pull that file as an attachment. I looked into various post like ( [Email .txt file as an attachment through Oracle Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373189/email-txt-file-as-an-attachment-through-oracle-stored-procedure) , [How can I send oracle query results by email. I would prefer attaching to email as excel file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299859/how-can-i-send-oracle-query-results-by-email-i-would-prefer-attaching-to-email) ), yet I am not getting what I am looking out for. Please help

Comment: *Why* haven't the questions you linked to solved your problem? If you've implemented one of those solutions and still have a problem with it then explain what that problem is. Otherwise you're just asking for repetition of the same answers.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes I didn't know how to bring that attachment into the mail. The user ( http://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit ) from one of the linked question asked me to refer to the post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607666/oracle-read-file-from-directory-with-exception ) so that I can take the file and put it into a BLOB variable. I need to check on that